# Apache doesn't serve files

Tags: linux, apache-httpd

I am setting up an Apache2 webserver and for some reason, it doesn't serve the files so I can access them via the web browser.
The document root is set to correctly and the files are owned by www-data (the same as the apache run as env variable).

If I try to access the file via ... .com/hello.txt, I get:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /hello.txt was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at ....... Port 80
```

My configuration file (some commented lines removed):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    #serverName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/linuxvm232b/public

    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    <Directory "/srv/www/linuxvm232b/public">
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF7fO.png)

Directory listing:

```
root@linuxvm232:/etc/apache2/sites-available# ll /srv/www/linuxvm232b/public/
total 14
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 6   Mar 4   14:58 assets
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 0   May 11  21:10 hello.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 907 Mar 4   14:58 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4 Mar 4 14:58 src
root@linuxvm232:/etc/apache2/sites-available#
```

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdYCY.png)

Comment: Please do not post pictures. You can copy & paste the text and use the `{}` (Code Sample) function instead. Did you enable your site using `a2ensite linuxvm232b` to symlink `sites-available/linuxvm232b.conf` in `sites-enabled`? Was the server restarted? What's in the log files?

Comment: It may be key here what you mean by `... .com/hello.txt`. Is that a domain? Is it configured? What makes you think so?

Comment: Yes the site is enabled and reachable via the domain, I just removed it for privacy reasons

Answer (score 0):

as I can see from your screenshots you are using the /srv directory to serve your files, which is not the default way on Debian as far as I can remember.

Make sure to check in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf that access for the apache server to the /srv directory is allowed as in the standard configuration, access to that directory is prohibited.

It should be a commented entry like this:

```
#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

Just uncomment that block and reload the apache2 via 
`systemctl reload apache2`
and directories in /srv should be able to be accessed.

Also be sure to have enabled the site via `a2ensite linuxvm232b` and `systemctl reload apache2`

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering, you were right, the block was commented, after uncommenting and reloading apache the page still doesn't get served. The site is already enabled

Comment: Hm, I see that the `ServerName` entry is commented out. Does anything change if you uncomment that and put in the domain name your are trying to use (and reloading the apache afterwards)?